# GAE: Not posting to local datastore (angular)

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, google-app-engine, webapp2

Ive got the following code. From chrome dev tools everythin is 200 OK and 302 after clicking post button but nothing is showing up on local datastore.

**"Recommendation" model**

```
class Recommendation(ndb.Model):
    comment = ndb.StringProperty()
```

**post method from python webapp2**

```
def post(self):
    r = json.loads(self.request.body)
    new_comment = Recommendation(comment=r['comment'])
    new_comment.put()
```

**/exp.html**

```html
<form ng-submit="addComment()" method="post" id="frmComment">  
 <textarea ng-model="formFields.comment" id="comment" name="comment" class="form-control status-box comment" rows="2"></textarea>
</form>

<div class="button-group pull-right">
<button form ="frmComment"class="btn btn-primary pst sameline" type="submit">Post</button>
</div>
```

**angular http post**

```
   $scope.formFields = {
        comment : ""
    }

   $scope.comments = [];

   $scope.addComment = function() {
        var form_comment = $scope.formFields.comment
        var payload = {
            comment: form_comment
        }
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/exp.html',
            data: payload
        }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.comments.push(payload);
            console.log(payload)
        }, function(response) { 
   });
```

Comment: 302 to where? that seems wrong if it's getting 302 since your post method does not have 302 redirect as response

Comment: @marcadian not sure what you mean by having 302 redirect as a response but this is what I get from the logs.                                >>INFO     2016-09-27 08:24:21,167 module.py:788] default: "POST /exp.html HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO     2016-09-27 08:24:21,229 module.py:788] default: "GET /exp.html HTTP/1.1" 200 12504

Comment: where is the redirect 302 to?

Comment: resolved!! my bad.. issue was I had pinned two handlers against /exp.html